# Прерывание ондой функцией другой функции

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Как реализовать две функции, чтобы при вызове одной прерывалась вторая и наоборот. Спасибо

Comment: Мы ничего не поняли (xотя какой-то "доброжелатель" и поставил вопросу "плюс"). Создайте пример.

Comment: простой вопрос, что тут непонятного. и кто это мы, раздвоение личности?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если речь об обычных функциях, то никак.
javascript -- *однопоточный* интерпретатор.
Можно попробовать переделать функцию в `async`/генератор,
чтоб исходный код функции оставался линейным,
а запуск происходил кусками по расписанию.

Comment: если совсем глубоко: https://habr.com/ru/post/461401/